# Installing mariadb 1.1.3 package on Python

Tags: installation, module, pip, mariadb, python-3.8

I am having some issues installing mariadb package on python 3.8 using pip3.

I tried to import mariadb library directly on my terminal using:

```
(scrap_venv) apnow@web:/var/sas/scrap$ python
Python 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mariadb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/sas/scrap_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mariadb/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ._mariadb import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mariadb._mariadb'
>>>
```

But it shows that the module is not found

I get this output if I launch `pip3 show mariadb`

```
Name: mariadb
Version: 1.1.3
Summary: Python MariaDB extension
Home-page: https://www.github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-python
Author: Georg Richter
Author-email:
License: LGPL 2.1
Location: /var/sas/scrap_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

Any idea?

All best,
Apnow

Comment: Does the directory   /var/sas/scrap_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mariadb contain _mariadb.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so? If yes, what is output of `ldd  /var/sas/scrap_venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mariadb/_mariadb.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`?

Comment: No, it doesn´t. there is no _mariadb.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so file on that path.

Comment: Try to reinstall mariab module: `pip3 uninstall mariadb`and `pip3 install --no-cache mariadb`