# Getting MariaDB ModuleNotFoundError in Python

Tags: python, mariadb

The error happens at the import line in the Python code.

```
sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb-connector-c/3.3.3")
sys.path.append("/usr/local/Cellar/mariadb-connector-c")

import mariadb
```

I already have the `mariadb` and `mariadb-1.1.5.post3.dist-info` added to the `sys.path`, I can see it when I do a `print (sys.path)`

The error message I am getting is : `Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError No module named 'mariadb._mariadb'`

`pip show mariadb` returns:

```
Name: mariadb
Version: 1.1.5.post3
Summary: Python MariaDB extension
Home-page: https://www.github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-python
Author: Georg Richter
Author-email: 
License: LGPL 2.1
Location: /Users/melinda.walker/GitHub/bi-ingestion-scripts/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: packaging
Required-by:
```

I am also using a virtual environment.
My  `python --version` is : `Python 3.9.16`

I used `brew install mariadb-connector-c` to install mariadb-connector-c.

It is similar to issues: [Installing mariadb 1.1.3 package on Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73148831/installing-mariadb-1-1-3-package-on-python) and [Python import Mariadb: 'ModuleNotFoundError'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74183866/python-import-mariadb-modulenotfounderror/74986311#74986311).

I tried what Georg suggested: `pip3 uninstall mariadb` and `pip3 install --no-cache mariadb` but I am still getting that error.

Comment: Did you start python from a directory which has a subdirectory mariadb?

Comment: This is the path to the file I am running with VSCode: `/myproject/confluence/execute.py` and this is the path to mariadb: `/myproject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mariadb/`